# design and assessment of qPCR primers for COVID19

Tags: molecular-biology, virology, primer

I read the False Negative of qPCR test for COVID19 is high compare to CT scans.

https://pubs.rsna.org/doi/10.1148/radiol.2020200642

I was curious if experts can comment on why and what makes it difficult to design more accurate PCR given the genomes is out there.

Comment: The WHO's primers are compatible with every sequences found so far, when the PCR fails it is because the sample doesn't contain enough viral genomes (here the probe https://blast.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Blast.cgi?CMD=Get&RID=607FNKGR01R )

Comment: what do you mean by compatible ? every test as sensitivity and specificity. here is the question, given the high match on blast - what makes it to have low specificity ? it is clear in the paper and other papers these pcr tests suffer from high false negative :)

Comment: Compatible means the forward and reverse primer (20 nt each) bind to the ends of the target 100 nucleotides subsequence of the viral genome (and its minus sense copy) and this subsequence contains the probe (25 nt). When extended by the TaQ polymerase the probe releases its quencher so that its fluorescent end produces light which is detected by the fluorometer. If some mutations appear in those three 20 nucleotides subsequences the PCR will stop working or it will be much less efficient and the WHO will have to make new primers with more diversity